# .htaccess - RewriteCond/RewriteRule to redirect all except a specific file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server-side

I have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/folder1(/.*|)$
RewriteRule         ^(.*)$  http://folder1.domain.com/  [R=301,L]
```

This results in taking me to

```
http://folder1.domain.com
```

if someone visits

```
http://www.domain.com/ANYTHINGHERE
```

I want to keep this functionality. **BUT I want the user to be able to view the file located at:**

```
http://www.domain.com/folder1/interestingfile.txt
```

when they visit either

```
http://www.domain.com/folder1/interestingfile.txt
```

**OR**

```
http://folder1.domain.com/interestingfile.txt
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a backreference:

```
RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/folder1/(.*|)$
RewriteRule         ^(.*)$  http://folder1.domain.com/%1  [R=301,L]
```

To backrefrence the part of the URI after `/folder1/`, assuming that you've got the `folder1.domain.com` document root pointing to the `/folder1/` folder.

Comment: I tried this, and it didnt seem to change the behavior in any way, i will read up on the backreferences

Answer (score 0):

Have your rules like this:

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)domain\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(folder1)/(interestingfile\.txt)$ http://$1.domain.com/$2 [R=301,L,NC]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)domain\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^folder1/ http://folder1.domain.com/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Make sure to:

1. Keep these rules before any other existing rules
2. Test in a new browser to avoid 301 caching